# Changing the location of H2 database configration file?

Tags: configuration, h2

H2 database manual says:

> The settings of the H2 Console are stored in a configuration file
>   called `.h2.server.properties` in you user home directory.

Is there any way to change the location of the configuration file to some specified directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-properties` setting as [documented in the Server tool](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#main_String...), as follows:

```
java -jar h2.jar -properties "/directory"
```